# What is the reason why this generic type not work but type alias is OK?

Tags: rust

I don't know why this code is not ok

```
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, Sender, Receiver};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct Worker;

impl Worker {
    fn new<T: FnOnce() + Send + 'static>(receiver: Arc<Mutex<Receiver<Box<T>>>>) -> Worker {
        Worker
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let rx: Arc<Mutex<Receiver<Box<FnOnce() + Send + 'static>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(rx));
    Worker::new(rx);
}
```

The compiler told me

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     Worker::new(rx);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send + 'static`
   |
   = note: `std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required by `Worker::new`
```

but when I use type alias like this, compilation is passed. Can anyone tell me the reason? I'm very confused ... In my opinion, the two methods is same, the type alias "Job" is just a shorten method.

```
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
struct Worker;

type Job = Box<FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

impl Worker {
    fn new(receiver: Arc<Mutex<Receiver<Job>>>)->Worker {
        Worker
    }
}

fn main(){
   let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
   let rx = Arc::new(Mutex::new(rx));
   Worker::new(rx);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify the vote: `T` is implicitly `Sized` in `Box<T> where T: FnOnce() + Send + 'static`, yet the first version attempts to call `Worker::new` where `T = (FnOnce() + Send + 'static)`, which is not sized. Just add `?Sized` to the constraint and it will compile: http://play.integer32.com/?gist=cbaff0acd0eb5842ef77da5d0201df33&version=stable

Comment: Thanks for you response! I want to know a little more, why in type alias version, I don't need to add the ?Sized trait?

Comment: That's because you don't have a type parameter in the second version at all. Had you declared `Job` like `type Job<T: FnOnce() + Send + 'static> = Box<T>;`, you would have had the same problem.

Comment: There's additional problem. It will compile, but it will not work. `Box<FnOnce()>` is unusable yet. `Box<Fn()>` should be used instead.

Comment: oh, I see.Can you tell me when should I add ?Sized? Feel like ?Size  doesn't make any sense, Why compiler don't add ?Size automatically for me?

Comment: @Frio, in this case you don't really need `?Sized` or generic `new<T>()`. I'll try to add answer a bit later.

Comment: I feel this was closed a bit prematurely, as the primary issue of the question in the title does not have to do with `Sized`, but the difference between trait objects and types that implements traits (i.e. `<T: SomeTrait> Box<T>` vs `Box<SomeTrait>`). Probably an answer for that somewhere as well, just have not found a one that matches this question well yet.

Comment: It seems I will not. Anyway, every closure, you seem to intend to pass into `Worker`, has unique type. Thus you will be able to pass exactly one closure into it. Other closures will have incompatible types. You'll need to use trait object `Box<Fn()>`, that is what you do in second version of your code.

Comment: @E_net4, please, consider removal of duplicate status.

Comment: @red75prime I do not have such a privilege, the OP has accepted the duplicate and it can only be retracted by voting to reopen or directly done so by a gold badge holder. Besides, it's not reasonable to reopen now without the question covering that concern, which was recently discovered. If the question is rephrased to ask about that problem in particular, then it's fair to reconsider.

Comment: @red75prime Why I have to use Fn()? The closure I want to pass is a task which would be processed only once.Is't it more suitable with FnOnce()?

Comment: @Frio, `Box<FnOnce()>` doesn't work yet, you get compilation error if you call it. [Issue #28796](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28796)

Comment: I couldn't really find a good question/answer to link to. So I wrote a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151770/what-is-the-difference-between-t-trait-boxt-and-boxtrait-in-rust/45151772#45151772

Comment: @ErikVesteraas Your new question/answers has resovled all my question now.thanks!