# What is the difference between <T: Trait> Box<T> and &Trait / Box<Trait>?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

When writing code with traits you can put the trait in a trait bound:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn myfunction1<T: Debug>(v: Box<T>) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn myfunction2<T: Debug>(v: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    myfunction1(Box::new(5));
    myfunction2(&5);
}
```

Or directly in a `Box` or reference type:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn myfunction3(v: Box<Debug>) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn myfunction4(v: &Debug) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    myfunction3(Box::new(5));
    myfunction4(&5);
}
```

These give the same output. So what is the difference?

(This question was inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148102/what-is-the-reason-why-this-generic-type-not-work-but-type-alias-is-ok#45148102) where this was just one of several intermingled concepts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `<T: Trait> Box<T>` you are using a trait bound to tell the compiler that you want a `Box` with an instance of some type `T` which implements `Trait`, and you will specify `T` when you use it. The Rust compiler will likely create different, efficient, code for each different `T` in your code (monomorphization).

With `Box<Trait>` you are telling the compiler that you want a `Box` with a trait object, a pointer to an *unknown* type which implements `Trait`, which means that the compiler will use dynamic dispatch.

I've included two examples which makes the difference a bit clearer:

`<T: Trait> Box<T>`, i.e. trait bound:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

struct Wrapper<T> {
    contents: Option<Box<T>>,
}

impl<T: Debug> Wrapper<T> {
    fn new() -> Wrapper<T> {
        Wrapper { contents: None }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, val: Box<T>) {
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut w = Wrapper::new();

    // makes T for w be an integer type, e.g. Box<i64>
    w.insert(Box::new(5));

    // type error, &str is not an integer type
    // w.insert(Box::new("hello"));
}
```

`Box<Trait>`, i.e. trait object:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

struct Wrapper {
    contents: Option<Box<Debug>>,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn new() -> Wrapper {
        Wrapper { contents: None }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, val: Box<Debug>) {
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut w = Wrapper::new();
    w.insert(Box::new(5));
    w.insert(Box::new("hello"));
}
```

For further details on the difference between trait bounds and trait objects I recommend [the section on trait objects in the first edition of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html).

Answer (score 5):

Importantly, you don't **have** to put the generic type behind a reference (like `&` or `Box`), you can accept it directly:

```
fn myfunction3<T: Debug>(v: T) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    myfunction3(5);
}
```

This has the same benefits of monomorphization without the downside of additional memory allocation (`Box`) or needing to keep ownership of the value somewhere (`&`).

I would say that generics should often be the default choice — you only require a *trait object* when there is dynamic dispatch / heterogeneity.