# How do I keep a mutable reference to the last node while building a linked list?

Tags: linked-list, rust, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement building a singly-linked list from an `Iterator`, keeping the order of elements.

The structure is defined as:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct List<T> {
    list: Node<T>,
}

type Node<T> = Option<Box<Link<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Link<T> {
    head: T,
    tail: Node<T>,
}
```

I was thinking of keeping a mutable reference to the end of the list and expanding it while iterating. However, I couldn't figure out how this could be done. The (non-working) idea was:

```
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn from_iterator(i: &mut Iterator<Item = T>) -> Self {
        let mut list = List { list: None };
        {
            let mut last: &mut Node<T> = &mut list.list;
            for x in i {
                let singleton = Box::new(Link {
                    head: x,
                    tail: None,
                });
                *last = Some(singleton);
                // --> I aim for something like the line below. Of course
                // 'singleton' can't be accessed at this point, but even if I
                // match on *last to retrieve it, still I couldn't figure out how
                // to properly reference the new tail.
                // last = &mut singleton.tail;
            }
        }
        list
    }
}
```

It'd be possible to just build the list in reverse and then reverse it afterwards with the same time complexity, but I was curious if the above approach is ever possible in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423), you can explicitly transfer ownership of the mutable reference using `{}`:

```
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn from_iterator<I>(i: I) -> Self
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    {
        let mut list = List { list: None };
        {
            let mut last: &mut Node<T> = &mut list.list;

            for x in i {
                let singleton = Box::new(Link {
                    head: x,
                    tail: None,
                });
                *last = Some(singleton);

                last = &mut {last}.as_mut().unwrap().tail;
            }
        }
        list
    }
}
```

I also removed the trait object (`&mut Iterator`) in favor of a generic. This allows for more optimized code (although with a linked list it's probably not worth it).

It's unfortunate that the `unwrap` is needed. Even though the `Link` is placed on the heap, making the address stable, the compiler does not perform that level of lifetime tracking. One *could* use `unsafe` code based on this external knowledge, but I don't know that it's worth it here.

Comment: Could you please also elaborate on the `&mut Iterator` comment and more optimized code? Is my intuition correct that using generics the compiler can specialize the function for different iterators?

Comment: @PetrPudlák does [What is the difference between <T: Trait> Box<T> and &Trait / Box<Trait>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45151770/155423) answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can do it in a loop.  The borrow checker might not be smart enough.  You can do it with recursion though.

```
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn from_iterator(i: &mut Iterator<Item = T>) -> Self {
        let mut list = List { list: None };
        Self::append_from_iterator(&mut list.list, i);
        list
    }
    pub fn append_from_iterator(list: &mut Node<T>, i: &mut Iterator<Item = T>) {
        match i.next() {
            Some(x) => {
                let mut singleton = Box::new(Link {
                    head: x,
                    tail: None,
                });
                Self::append_from_iterator(&mut singleton.tail, i);
                *list = Some(singleton);
            }, 
            None => (),
        }

    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=df0f9bafca02357e30f11796cadaa069&version=stable)

Comment: Your `match` should be an `if let`.

Comment: Won't the recursion be a problem for big lists? Unless the compiler is smart enough to convert it to tail recursive calls, which doesn't seem probable.

Comment: Yes, that's a basic tradeoff between recursion and looping.